# Parse contig.exe output to *.csv using command-line or PowerShell

Tags: command-line, powershell, defragment

I am trying to parse the output file from contig.exe into a a comma-separated value file.  I've developed a method to do this is Notepad++, but given the number of files I have to parse (hundreds of text files) I would like to have an automated method using either command-line or PowerShell.

For example, I would like to turn this:

```
Contig v1.7 - Makes files contiguous
Copyright (C) 1998-2012 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


Processing E:\$Mft...
E:\$Mft is in 80309 fragments

Processing E:\$Mft::$BITMAP...
E:\$Mft::$BITMAP is in 2202 fragments

Summary:
     Number of files processed   : 2
     Average fragmentation       : 41255.5 frags/file
```

...into this:

```
E:\$Mft,80309 fragments
E:\$Mft::$BITMAP,2202 fragments
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure Notepad++ allows you to search+replace in multiple files at once, and you can probably use RegEx to retain only the lines that start with "Drive:\" and end in "fragments".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powershell, you just apply your regex using the `-match` operator and then output each match separated by commas:

```
contig.exe | foreach-object{ if($_ -match "(.*) is in (.*)") {"`"$($Matches[1])`",`"$($Matches[2])`""}}
```

output:

```
"E:\$Mft","80309 fragments" 
"E:\$Mft::$BITMAP","2202 fragments"
```

Note that I have enclosed the columns with quotes to handle columns with spaces